# Android - Integrate GitHub library in xamarin project

Tags: android, xamarin, dll, xamarin.android

I want to use the `sdp` unit (sdp (scalable dp). It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens) in my Android Xamarin project and it is available only on `GitHub`. 
On github, they proposed to add `sdp` using `build.gradle` which is not available in Xamarin. So how can I integrate and use this library in my project on Visual studio (xamarin) ? Link to the library on GitHub: [the library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no code and only "resources" in `com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android`, so while you could create a `Xamarin.Android` binding library for the `sdp` AAR file, it would be more efficient to just copy those resources from the GitHub project to a Xamarin.Android application/library project:

Android Studio/gradle project:

```
└── res
    ├── layout
    │   ├── dp_example.xml
    │   └── sdp_example.xml
    ├── values
    │   ├── negative_sdps.xml
    │   └── positive_sdps.xml
    ~~~~~
    └── values-sw780dp
        ├── negative_sdps.xml
        └── positive_sdps.xml
```

Xamarin.Android project:

```
└── Resources
    ├── layout
    │   ├── dp_example.xml
    │   └── sdp_example.xml
    ├── values
    │   ├── negative_sdps.xml
    │   └── positive_sdps.xml
    ~~~~~
    └── values-sw780dp
        ├── negative_sdps.xml
        └── positive_sdps.xml
```

Comment: Beside question if you have an experience in this library, there is no need now to create multiple layouts for different `dp` ? Can I use one layout without creating multiple file for different screen sizes ?

Comment: @Wassim01 It really depends upon your layouts (assuming we are not talking about tablet-based orientation/screens), all those resources do are apply different `dp` units based upon the different device sizes, so sometimes it works out well, but again you would made to test it on your layouts.